# Why homebrew installed nginx only serve files in the default doc root?

Tags: php, macos, nginx, homebrew

I installed nginx (with --fpm) on Mac OS X through homebrew, but I can't make it serve php files (html files are OK). Here is the error:

> [error] 46118#0: *1 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1,
>   server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"

below is my site conf file.

```
server {
    listen  80;

    root /Users/me/Sites/test/public/;
    index index.html index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /Users/me/Sites/test/public/scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'm not very well versed in the fpm setup. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thanx.

Environment:
  Mac OS X 10.10.2
  nginx:1.6.2

Comment: Have you php-fpm server running?

Comment: Having the same issue since I upgrade to 10.10.2